# Fixed size array in ink smart contract storage

Tags: ink, storage

How can I have a fixed size array in my ink smart contract storage?

E.g.

```
    // Contract storage
    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct MyContract {
        myArray: [u8; 64]
    }
```

I get "the trait `StorageLayout` is not implemented for `[u8; 64]`" as the error during compilation.

I don't want to use a `Vec<u8>` as I would have to do size checks all over the place to ensure it's consistently 64 elements long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved via an issue raised on the (ink github)[https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1787]. This will be available in releases post ink v4.2.